# select data from database with where selected any rows

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create function to search data from my MySql database. My search form contains three fields. Into these field user can put some text/value or not.. Like in normal search form..
But i fight with some problem - laravel don't return my any values...
I use:

```
Input::get('bus', 'Business.ID');
```

To replace null values inserted by user to every value
and next in:

```
-> where('Business.ID', '=', $bus)
```

i try to search values...
But unfortunately it always return empty table in my json .. How can i reach my goal?
My whole code and commented lines i tried

```
public function searchVoucher(){
    //$input = Input::all();
    // if(!isset($input['business'])){
    //  $bus = 'Business.ID';
    // }
    $bus = Input::get('bus', 'Business.ID');
    $company = Input::get('company', 'Companies.Comp_Name');
    $city = Input::get('city', 'Companies.City');
// SELECT * FROM Vouchers
// INNER JOIN Companies
// ON Vouchers.ID_Company = Companies.ID
// Inner JOIN Business
// on Companies.Business_Id = Business.ID
// where Business.ID = Business.ID

    $results = DB::table('Vouchers')
                //-> select('Vouchers.ID', 'URL as Url', 'Vou_Name as Name', 'Comp_Name', 'Discount', 'Quantity', 'Date')
                -> Join('Companies', 'Vouchers.ID_Company', '=', 'Companies.ID')
                -> Join('Business', 'Companies.Business_ID', '=', 'Business.ID')
                -> where('Business.ID', '=', $bus)  
                //-> whereRaw("Business.ID =$bus")// and Companies.Comp_Name =$company and Companies.City = $city")
                //-> whereRaw("Companies.Comp_Name =$company")
                -> where('Companies.Comp_Name', '=', $company)
                -> get();

    //if($results){
        return Response::json(['SearchList' => $results,'bus'=>$bus, 'success' => 1]);
    // }else {
    //  return Response::json(['SearchList'=>'No vouchers found', 'success'=>0]);
    // }            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

> ```
> Input::get('bus', 'Business.ID');
> ```
>
> To replace null values inserted by user to every value and next in:
>
> ```
> -> where('Business.ID', '=', $bus)
> ```

You are defining a default value for your input, so this query;

```
$results = DB::table('Vouchers')
  -> Join('Companies', 'Vouchers.ID_Company', '=', 'Companies.ID')
  -> Join('Business', 'Companies.Business_ID', '=', 'Business.ID')
  -> where('Business.ID', '=', $bus)  
  -> where('Companies.Comp_Name', '=', $company)
  -> get();
```

It's probably doing something like this:

```
$results = DB::table('Vouchers')
  -> Join('Companies', 'Vouchers.ID_Company', '=', 'Companies.ID')
  -> Join('Business', 'Companies.Business_ID', '=', 'Business.ID')
  -> where('Business.ID', '=', 'Business.ID')  
  -> where('Companies.Comp_Name', '=', 'Companies.Comp_Name')
  -> get();
```

This is what you have to do, incremental queries:

```
$myQuery = DB::table('Vouchers')
    ->Join('Companies', 'Vouchers.ID_Company', '=', 'Companies.ID')
    ->Join('Business', 'Companies.Business_ID', '=', 'Business.ID');
if (Input::has('bus'))
{
    $myQuery = $myQuery-> where('Business.ID', '=', Input::get('bus'));
}
if (Input::has('company'))
{
    $myQuery = $myQuery> where('Companies.Comp_Name', '=', Input::get('company'));
}
if (Input::has('city'))
{
    $myQuery = $myQuery> where('Companies.City', '=', Input::get('city'));
}
$results = $myQuery->get();
```

You could also extract all of this into eloquent scopes,

Comment: Glad I could help you out! ;)